# Why would a jQuery function be only selectively run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I am trying to debug this (incomplete) script, but it is behaving inconsistently. The main problem is when I click off of an item, sometimes the `$(editObj).removeAttr('style');` runs and sometimes not. Through the Chrome inspector I can see that the editObj variable in each case is properly defined, but it isn't always getting its inline style attribute removed. Sometimes, and sometimes not. Cannot determine the reason.

I'm a bit out of my element with this code. Maybe something about it is obvious; Regardless I'd appreciate some ideas on why this sort of unpredictable might be occuring!

```
    var editObj = null;
    var inputType = 'text';
    var input = '#textEdit';
    var formId = '#form_undefined'

$(function() {
$("#textEdit").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('body').click(function(event) {
        if (editObj){


            //textedit contents to editobj and 
            if (inputType == 'text'){
                $(editObj).text($("#textEdit").val());
            }
            $("#textEdit").removeAttr('style').hide();

            $(editObj).removeAttr('style');
            var previewId = $(editObj).attr('id');
            var formId = previewId.replace('bzm', 'form');
            $("#" + formId).val($("#textEdit").val());

            //ajax modify database
            editObj = null;
        }
    });

    $(".editable").not("video, img, textarea")
    .click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        loadEditor($(this));
    });
});

function loadEditor(element){

    $("#textEdit")
        .copyCSS(element)
        .offset($(element).offset())
        .css("display", "block")
        .val($(element).text())
        .select();

    $(element).css("color", "transparent");

    editObj = element;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had trouble in the past with `.removeAttr('style');` not actually removing all the inline styles.

Use

```
$(editObj).attr('style', '');
```

instead of

```
$(editObj).removeAttr('style');
```

Comment: I thought I had tried that, but.. it does work! Logic to me indicates there should be no difference in performance there.. is the way I had it buggy, or what?

Comment: @Damon: Honestly, I have no idea. I would assume that your way should work (that's how I would have written it), but I've had way too much trouble with this in the past, so I just resort to `.attr('style', '');`. It might be a bug in jQuery. Dunno.

Answer (score 0):

I dint see any code that initializes e editobj variable.. May be Im missing Anthony.. Anyways what are the chances of the edit obj being null.. Just put a log statement in the click function to always log ur editobj and see if it is null smtimes

Comment: there will be times when I'd like to skip the function caused by a body click.. when no area is being edited. It will also help me tracking clicks from one element to another w/o hitting the body in between